# Implementing Session Expiration and Login Page Navigation in Blazor Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor

How can I implement a feature in a Blazor application to automatically expire a user's login after 5 minutes of inactivity, display an error message, and navigate them to the login page? I would like to know the steps and code required to achieve this using Blazor in C#

This is the modification I made in the MainLayout.zazor component to enable the session expiration feature. However, it appears that the functionality is not working as expected. Can you please assist me in troubleshooting the issue?

```
 @code {
    private bool loginSuccess;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        loginSuccess = LoginService.GetLoginSuccess();

        if (loginSuccess)
        {
            StartSessionTimer();
        }
    }

    private async Task StartSessionTimer()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

        await localStore.RemoveItemAsync("userLogin");

        NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.